# Standard syntax $_POST[''] returns false/drops data before parse to variable

Tags: php, parsing, post, mysqli, get

Sup stackies.

Okay, i have got a real head scratcher for you guys! I've been trying to solve this puzzle for a week now (apparently i was on stack cooldown). Ok so whats going on is that i have 2 scripts, that goes under the same if/elseif statement. They both work 100% individually (multiple tests were taken to conclude this). The script is supposed to start the if/elseif depending on one of 2 submit buttons. the scripts themselves is not the problem. It's the process of starting the scripts. On the same page as the 2 submit buttons, there is 2 "text" fields, that both of the scripts utilize to complete.

The buttons is build like this:

```
<input type="SUBMIT" Name="Udlaan"  VALUE="Udlån" METHOD="POST" class="Aside-Udlån">
<input type="SUBMIT" Name="Aflever"  VALUE="Aflever" METHOD="POST" class="Aside-aflever" >
```

They work.

The text fields are build like this:

```
<input Type="Text" Name="bunnr" Method="POST" Class="Skriv_bun" Placeholder="bun Nummer">
<input Type="Text" Name="Ordreren" Method="POST" Class="Ordre_No_Skriv" Placeholder="Ordre Nummer">
```

The variables that holds the data from the textfield looks like this:

```
$Ordre_Nr=$_POST['Ordreren'];
$bun_Nr=$_POST['bunnr'];
```

So the problem is that the data from the text field is never getting parsed into the variablesm, which causes my scripts to never run . (I mind you that the input fields and the variables are 3 lines apart with nothing inbetween nor above the textfields that has any relevance to this problem.) I added in `or die($conn);` on one of the variables, which gave me "Object of class mysqli could not be converted into string". Without it, the above just returns false with undefined index.

I tried making new scripts that is in no way connected to my real script. 
This is one of them:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form METHOD="POST">  <input type="submit" Method="POST" NAME="WORLD" Placeholder="World">
  <input type="text" Method="POST" NAME="Hello" Placeholder="hej">

  </form>
 <?php
 $f = $_POST['World'];
 $e = $_POST['hej'];
 if(isset($f)){echo $e;}
 ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Do we agree that this should work? well it doesn't. Nothing, sip, nada. except the same "Undefined index".
I made another quite like the one above(Almost exactly like it) using `POST` aswell, the data i put in the text field came out as `GET` (I could see everything in the url bar).

This isn't just a standard error, i had a guy with 20 years (on/off) of experience look at it, and he could not find a single syntax error, that could be related to this issue.

If anyone has any really good suggestions, please come forth and prevail! And should you be in need for more information, i will try my best to provide ^^

Fyi, i don't care much for "SQL injection comments, since it's not important for this issue.
Fyi 2. This is NOT a duplicate. I have checked multiple questions with answers for this issue, nothing has worked.

Comment: why are you putting method in each input?

Comment: On your `<input Type="Text" Name="bunnr" Method="POST" Class="Skriv_bun" Placeholder="bun Nummer">`, `Method="POST"` is not HTML5 correct. This attribute has to be set on `<form>` opening tag.

Comment: I have tried putting it in the top, the bottom, back and forth, it hasn't done anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a form the method should only go into the `<form>` tag as shown in my example below:

**Note** that I have used `name="sendPost"` as the name for submit button.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="world" placeholder="World">
    <input type="text" name="hello" placeholder="hej">
    <input type="submit" name="sendPost" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then within the PHP you need to check if the sent has been submitted:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sendPost']))
{
    $f = $_POST['world'];
    $e = $_POST['hello'];

    echo $e, $f;
}

?>
```

Therefore, If isset sendPost (if sendPost has been pressed run this query)

Also note, the PHP should go above the html rather than below.

**Added to:**

Else if's again run pretty simple, here's an addition to my initial answer:

Take a form and add 2 submits instead of one.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="world" placeholder="World">
    <input type="text" name="hello" placeholder="hej">
    <input type="submit" name="sendPost" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset Form">
</form>
```

Then within the PHP after your **IF** has closed you can run elseif (something else) such as my added example:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sendPost']))
{
    $f = $_POST['world'];
    $e = $_POST['hello'];

    echo $e, $f;
} elseif (isset($_POST['reset']))
{
    echo 'the form has been reset';
}

?>
```

Therefore, if sendPost has been submitted run whats within the brackets and echo out `$e` and `$f`. Else if you've pressed Reset run the echo of `the form has been reset`.

Comment: I tried that multiple times, with`method="POST" `  in `<form>` tag only, in input only and both. Nothing.

Comment: Have you actually tried using my example on wherever you're coding?

Comment: I just have (My scripts is very very similar so i didn't before.) Yours seems to be working. But that still doesn't explain why the data isn't parsed with my variables. Since the data from the fields should be saved in the variables without the `Isset`

Comment: I've added to my answer to give you a better example of adding in the `elseif` query also.

Comment: How do you expect it to know where to save if you haven't ran an isset? I see no PHP within your question therefore can only answer what's been provided.

Comment: Yours isn't working because of: `if(isset($f)){echo $e;}` try changing yours to how mine looks and pass feedback.

Comment: Top code snippet, there is the PhP. Which should fill the variables then run the if statement (I've done it before, were it worked)

Comment: Yours is working like it should. And that is why it's confusing me so much ^^

Comment: Even running it with your initial variables it makes no difference as long as you follow what I have already told you.. You have a working answer here there's no need really for me to respond any further.. **Look at my code and then look at yours. See what I have already told you about the `isset()`**

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i'm thrilled that you helped me ^^ I'm just trying to really understand why this was happening ^^

Comment: I've already explained more than once. Read it through. Your `isset()` was incorrect. Not only that, you have `method=post` scattered everywhere when it didn't need to be.

Comment: That was the compined answer i was looking for ^^ Thanks alot man! <3 <3